# Search Document Library in a site

Tags: sharepoint-search, keywordquery

I would like to search only document libraries in a site(not the document). I tried below search but its returning documents within the document library.

path:"http://localhost/managedpath/sitename" and contentclass:"STS_List"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this page that gives more examples of the other contentclasses you can use for your search query. 
[SharePoint Power Searching Using ContentClass](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2015/02/16/sharepoint-power-searching-using-contentclass/)

See the List ContentClass codes table where STS_List_DocumentLibrary might do the trick.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Can you please let me know from which managed property I can get the list title. The title managed property is returning "Site Title" as a prefix. Is there a way I can get the Document Library Title?

Comment: Hello, When I did a test using a search box, refiner, and results web part I set the following in my results query and it displays the Document Libraries by name in the search results: path:"https://localhost/managedpath/sitename" contentclass:"STS_List_DocumentLibrary"

Comment: Not sure why it's giving me the Site Title.

Comment: I am able to get document libraries but it's not showing the libraries if there are no documents in it. Is this expected behavior?

Comment: @RaviKhambhati Were you able to resolve issue of Site Name getting prefixed?

Comment: @Mani Sorry but its been a while so don't recollect what approach I took.